# Get users FBID from leadgen webhook

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get fbid of the user from leadgen form? i checked LeadgenInfo Node https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/user-lead-gen-info/ and was not able to find the appropriate field.

I need FBid to get persons profile information and send automated response to messenger.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to fetch such data.

Instead this is what you can do - include either email or mobile number field to your leadgen form and do follow up on the same.

or

You can also launch click to messenger campaigns on Ad Manager.